# Using Android location updates efficiently

Tags: android, location

I have just started playing with the location services that android provides, I was thinking about the following code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      //update textview
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

When the location updates I was going to update a text view with the speed using the `getSpeed()` method that is available.

My question is, does this nuke the battery life of the phone? if so, are there more efficient ways of doing it? like registering a `BroadcastReceiver` to get the location updates? I'm just looking for ways that I can use the Location updates in a way that is efficient for maximising battery life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android
>   framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location
>   awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android
>   framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the
>   Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible.

Source: [Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

I have used it and found the following to be quite efficient, esp in terms of nuking the battery vs obtaining the location frequently, accurately:

*1.*  Use [Fused Location Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html), [GoogleApiClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html):

```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
           .addApi(LocationServices.API)
           .build();
           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

*2.*  Use [LocationRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html) according to the requirement:

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();    
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(120000);
    //there are other options associated with this objects
    // including types of priority
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

*3.*  Set the LocationServices to use a `this` if class implements `LocationListener` or define a new one in:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                     mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

All components are under the package

```
com.google.android.gms
```

[gms/location/package-summary](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html)

Reference: [googlesamples/android-play-location](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location)

Comment: I had briefly looked at the google play services API's guess I will have to work it

Comment: Shouldn't cause a problem unless google play services isn't available on the device

Comment: FusedLocationApi is deprecated